# To the Catholic, is the Saviour is in a form of historical time?

Tags: catholicism

My Catholic friend told me that historical Jesus is the only Savior for human kind. I asked him, *Why did God delay His action to save human kind ?*. He answered *"It's up to Him. That is what He will"*. Although his answer is logical and definitely can shout my mouth up, but to be honest I'm not satisfied with his answer.

I told my friend that (imho) God Himself is the Savior, that's why it's difficult for me to grasp that *historical Jesus is the only Savior for human kind*. I still can understand if *God is the only Savior for human kind*, as there is no time relative involved. In my imagination, if Jesus is The Word of God then The Word of God (not in a flesh) is given through out human history, since Adam and Eve until the judgment day. For the illustration, (in my imagination) *after the fall - God still in "contact" with Adam and Eve to save them*. But then my friend respond me that my illustration is unbiblical because there is no proof in the Bible that God still in "contact" with Adam and Eve to save them after the fall.

Again, my friend's respond definitely shut my mouth up because of course since it's only my own imagination then it is without biblical basis :).

So, *Why did God delay His action to save human kind ?* according to Catholic - besides the answer is *It's up to Him. That is what He will"* ?

Comment: The Eastern Orthodox perspective on this is that the earth had to be prepared to receive the Incarnate Savior, with the entire Old Testament documenting how God sought out righteous people who were willing to cooperate with His grace.  I believe a term that German theologians use for this is "Heilsgeschicht" - "Salvation history".  The Virgin Mary also figures prominently in this understanding, as, according to Eastern Orthodox thought at least she was the first woman who was worthy to bear the Savior.  Orthodoxy and Catholicism diverge on why this is true of her, though.

Comment: I submit the above as a comment rather than an answer, as you are asking for the Roman Catholic perspective - but I thought it was worth contributing since some traditions are common between the Orthodox and Roman Catholics.

Comment: @karma, John the Evangelist teaches us, that Jesus was from the beginning, that is to say, while there was a time before Jesus took on  his human nature,  as Paul wrote to the Colossians (in 1:17) "He is before all things and in him all things hold together". In other words, there was no time "before Jesus was born".

Comment: @brasshat, that's what I mean. I just don't understand why in my friend's pov that historical Jesus is the only Savior to human kind. Except if he added a time frame : "the human kind who lives during His time and to the future times", then to me it is more acceptable :).

Comment: @guest37, I think your sentence *"Salvation history"* more or less is the same with brasshat sentence *"string of actions intended to save human kind"*. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a catholic, I deny that God delayed his action to save Humankind, because God implemented actions to save Mankind before Jesus. Two are Noah being saved by the ark from the deluge, and Moses receiving the law at Mt. Sinai as the testament of God's original covenant with his chosen people. God's salvific action in the suffering, death, resurrection, and ascension of Jesus, should be viewed as the most recent in string of actions intended to save human kind. God did not delay his action, rather, when a previous action failed, he instituted another.

As to your friend's suggestion that there is no proof in the Bible that Jesus was in contact with Adam and Eve to save them, he is correct: there is not. But neither is there anything in the Bible to prove that God is not in contact with Adam and Eve, either,  so your friend seems to be using the questionable tactic of the "testimony of silence".

Comment: brasshat, what you explain above is similar in my thinking. Specifically in this sentence *"God's salvific action in the suffering, death, resurrection, and ascension of Jesus, should be viewed as the most recent in **string of actions intended to save human kind**"*. Thank you for your explanation.